# How to Cache dynamic content using Nginx when sessions are involved?

Tags: nginx, cache

[This link explains how to create static files from dynamic content using Nginx](http://mark.ossdl.de/2009/07/nginx-to-create-static-files-from-dynamic-content/).

My question is this: can I achieve the same **if login sessions are involved**. ie. when I want to serve content to **only registered users** and not otherwise. So how to overcome sessions when it comes to caching and finally to use the cache next time for another session?

*Detailed scenario:*

The goal of my website is to serve content to only registered users.

There are plenty of users logged in, each having different session IDs.

> A php page queries the DB and finds "XYZ" that user "A" wants and generates HTML output.
>
> Now if user "B" ***(with a different session ID)*** after sometime wants the same "XYZ", how to make Nginx to deliver from cache without making the php page to query the db again.
>
> Has anybody done this before?

---

Clarification regarding possible question dupes:

[nginx caching dynamic content to static](https://serverfault.com/questions/225013/nginx-caching-dynamic-content-to-static)
My question is caching dynamic content **when sessions are involved**. The above question is more general (no mention about sessions).

Comment: HTTP is all around resources (URI) and headers. I cannot grasp what you mean under "XYZ" in your question, how you identify cookies, etc. -- it would be helpful if you could define your question in technical terms.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll be better off looking at [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) for this, nginx has very limited caching functionality.

With nginx you can detect cookie data and use that to force the user a different cache key as shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130317092133/https://syslog.tv/2010/04/18/new-syslog-tv-nginx-wordpress-site-configuration/), but this probably isn't enough for what you want to do.

Comment: Second link has broken, content is available at the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20130317092133/https://syslog.tv/2010/04/18/new-syslog-tv-nginx-wordpress-site-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpSsiModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSsiModule) wherever you need dynamic works (Session vs.)